# How can I get a row which has biggest value?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-order-by, max, limit

I got query like this

```
SELECT 
  IMAGE_PATH, IMAGE_ID, DOC_NID 
FROM
  TBL_IMAGE WHERE IMAGE_ORD = 1
```

And have follow conditions

- image_ord should br changed to image_ord=max value
- image_ord column is number type and it has some duplication
- I need only one row with biggest value of image_ord
- it could be handled deal with rownum, but I do not want to Since it has many layers above this.(It is subquery)

Could it be handled without subquery?

Comment: It is not quite clear to me: if _"image_ord [...] has some duplication"_ and you _"need only one row with biggest value of image_ord"_ how do you discriminate between the various rows having the same maximal `image_ord` ?

Comment: @SylvainLeroux it has several rows with value 1. I know it is wrong DB plan, however it is not a sequence, just number type column. anyway, when I do 'order by', the first row is always same.

Comment: `ORDER BY` what ? If this is `ORDER BY IMAGE_ORG` you shouldn't rely on the fact that the rows are retrieved in any particular order for the _same_ `IMAGE_ORG`  value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your requirements:

> "image_ord [...] has some duplication"
>
> "I need only one row with biggest value of image_ord"

```
WITH C AS ( SELECT MAX(IMAGE_ORD) M FROM TBL_IMAGE )
SELECT 
  TBL_IMAGE.IMAGE_PATH, TBL_IMAGE.IMAGE_ID, TBL_IMAGE.DOC_NID 
FROM
  TBL_IMAGE JOIN C ON IMAGE_ORD = C.M
WHERE ROWNUM < 2
```

- The `WITH ...`  statement will retrieve the maximum value for the `image_ord` field
- The `SELECT ...` statement will use a `JOIN` on the temporary table above
- The `WHERE ROWNUM < 2` will limit the number of result to 1 row

Please note that in absence of an (unambiguous) `ORDER BY` clause, the result from the `SELECT` statement should be considered as an unordered set of row. So in case of duplicates, you shouldn't rely on any particular row (nor even the same row) being returned. Just *"one"* row having the maximum `image_ord` value.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I worry about duplication of image_ord values also, but I do not know yet how to avoid this. Anyway, I like your wonderful answer especially using 'with'. That makes more clear and nice :D Thanks so much b

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT 
  IMAGE_PATH, IMAGE_ID, DOC_NID, Max(image_ord) 
FROM
  TBL_IMAGE WHERE IMAGE_ORD = 1 group by IMAGE_PATH, IMAGE_ID, DOC_NID
```

Comment: Well, if you search for `max(image_ord)` then `where image_ord = 1` statement is out of place.

Comment: So just removing where condition might help in this case ?

Answer (score 0):

I solve my own problem with follow query.
Anyway, I had to use sub query and add some extra functions to use in upper bracket.

```
select 
  doc_nid, max(image_ord) as image_ord 
from 
  (
    select 
      doc_nid, nvl(image_ord, 0) as image_ord
    from
      tbl_image 
    where 
      doc_nid is not null
  )
group by doc_nid
```